# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in

Tags: error, magento-2.1

I am getting this error in given file while checkout am unable to process any Order.

`../pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules.js`

Answer (score 1):

Stores > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > 
Name and Address Options: Number of Lines in a Street Address make it 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like a default magento error.

The bug is discussed here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4921

The commit for solve this is here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7fb8a9c0ede398c661f001ac22fa4fb7dc642b2b